# Viewing my db when developing in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am new to windows phone 8 development and I am using the LINQ - SQL technique in developing my database. My code works without displaying any error. But my challenge now is I don't know were I can actually view my database to be sure that it is created and there are values inserted into it in visual studio. I check the database explorer but did not find it there. 
I know that in android we have the Log cat, file explorer that display the phone file system.
Does windows phone 8 emulator have anything of this sort.
I have been searching online but yet to lay my hands on any useful material on this issue.

Thanks alot

Comment: have you tried sqlite for windows phone 8. because it have sufficient info available for working with it.for it i can help you.

Comment: nope are you suggesting I use sqlite. Rather than the database context techniques

Comment: but even with the database context techniques I shuld be able to know were the database is created and stored

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Windows Phone Power Tools to explore the file system that your application is using. http://wptools.codeplex.com

Then you can import the database file form the device (or emulator) to your computer and use a database engine (or tool) for accessing the database and check the content.

The Windows Phone SDK has a command line tool for accessing the file system (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286408(v=vs.105).aspx ), however I don't use it at all, I prefer the Power tools

Cheers,
Herber